# Acces violation while scaling with a composite transform on wp8.1

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, windows-phone-8.1, scale

I have created a flashlight app for Windows Phone. As i already acces the camera to enable the flash, i thought it would be a nice feature to also allow the user to view the previewframes, and be able to zoom in to get a better look at things.

I have a canvas with a composite transform (as i also have to rotate the camera to match potrait mode). I use a slider (started with pinch, but i want one hand control) to increase and decrease the scale of the canvas, effectively zooming in and out. So far so good and on windows Phone 8 (HTC 8x) this works fine, i can go crazy on the slider and nothing bad happens.

On Windows Phone 8.1 (Lumia 930) however, at seemingly randoms moments when moving the slider, the app just closes down and in the debug output the following line is shown:

The program '[3164] TaskHost.exe' has exited with code -1073741819 (0xc0000005) 'Access violation'.

I have no idea how to find the cause of this as the moment of the crash seems to be different, its just Always related to the scaling of the canvas. I am hoping someone can point me in the right direction so i can solve this.

The canvas in XAML:

```
        <Canvas x:Name="viewfinderCanvas">
            <Canvas.Background>
                <VideoBrush x:Name="viewfinderBrush"/>
            </Canvas.Background>
            <Canvas.RenderTransform>
                <CompositeTransform x:Name="rt" />
            </Canvas.RenderTransform>
        </Canvas>
```

And my code for setting the scale:

```
    private void Zoom_ValueChanged(object sender, RoutedPropertyChangedEventArgs<double> e)
    {
        if (canZoom && !isFocusing)
        {
            zoomValue = Math.Round(Zoom.Value, 1);

            rt.ScaleX = zoomValue * staticValue;
            rt.ScaleY = zoomValue * staticValue;
            ZoomValue.Text = zoomValue.ToString() + " x";
        }
    }
```

Where canzoom is set to true on the loaded event of the mainpage, and isFocusing is set to true upon the autofocus.

Comment: Have you tried displaying a simple static Image instead of a VideoBrush? Just to test if it would still crash.

Comment: Tried, and it doesn't appear to crash, thanks. As the problem appears to be with the audiovideocapture device, i'll retarget my app and create a WP 8.1 specific package using the new MediaCapture device, hoping for better results with that.